# Is it possible to call WinMain from regular main?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In particular, is there a way to create a windows application without directly specifying it with the 'new project' wizard? Obviously simply including "windows.h" does not automatically create a main function, so if I wanted to create a windows application "from scratch" how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Hmm what compiler? What environment? Simplest program contains main function (C++ standard requirement), and you can just run compiler from the shell on it - you don't need any smart wizards at all.

Comment: Trying this out in visual studio

Comment: For those of you reading this in the ~future~. I've since learned (from *Windows via C++*) that you can toggle the subsystem (in Visual Studio) by going to Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > System > SubSystem. If you set it to *Not Set*, then you can use either `main` or `WinMain` (the compiler will infer). As *Windows via C++* mentions, this should probably be set by default (it isn't), but then again there's plenty of wackiness to go around in Win32 programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

icktoofay's answer is mostly right, save for one part:

> That's what happens in a standard C program, but you can use `WinMain` instead, which is not standard. If `main` is not present but `WinMain` is, it will call `WinMain` instead with the appropriate parameters.

The deciding factor in what an application's secondary entry point (the function called by `start` or `_start` is) is which [subsystem is specified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fcc1zstk.aspx) to the linker.

If you're building manually, you can add the `/SUBSYSTEM` switch to the linker command line to specify that you're building a Windows application (that will expect a `WinMain` or `wWinMain` entry point) as opposed to a console application (that will expect a `main` or `wmain` entry point). If you're building from Visual Studio, you can choose the subsystem in the linker settings of the C++ project properties.

Comment: I feel like a complete novice saying this, but what is `start`? I've been programming for years (albeit not in C++, though I'm far from new to it) and have never heard of that.

Comment: `start` or `_start` is a function that is automatically linked in by the C runtime you're using (such as the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime or glibc) behind the scenes, that takes care of some initialization details and calls your entry point (like `main` or `WinMain`) for you. It does things like initialize global and static variables and prepare the entry point's arguments. All of this happens transparently and silently in the background.

Comment: Ah, so in essence I need to stop begin a wuss and learn about compilation/linking. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, the runtime-provided entry point is an implementation detail that you won't need to know a whole lot about to move forward. Just make sure you understand your compiler and linker options so your results can be what you expect.

Answer (score 6):

When a program starts up, the `start` or `_start` function is called. The definition of this function is included in a library that is usually automatically linked in. In a standard C program, it will do some start-up things and then call your `main` function.

That's what happens in a *standard* C program, but you can use `WinMain` instead, which is not standard. If `main` is not present but `WinMain` is, it will call `WinMain` instead with the appropriate parameters.

As such, it is not necessary to have a `main` function; `WinMain` serves that purpose rather than `main`.

Comment: Since the signature is `WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)` how would I create an `HINSTANCE` ?

Comment: @sircodesalot - `HINSTANCE` is defined in 'windows.h" so just `#include <windows.h>`

Comment: Right, but that somehow needs to be passed into `WinMain`, so how would I do that?

Comment: @sircodesalot: `start` will call [`GetStartupInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683230.aspx) for you. Why not use `WinMain` in the first place, though? `WinMain` needs no more special treatment than `main` does; I've successfully created small applications containing `WinMain` with just command-line compiler tools.

Comment: I agree. GCC is nice and accepts both `int main()` and `WinMain` without any need for projects.